# How to use animated gif tiles in leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, animation, dictionary, leaflet, gif

I'm currently developing a web application that fetch non-geographical-imagery (custom image tiles) from my own server and display it on the map.
It works fine with static tiles for now.

Looking for a solution to enable changing multiple frames of (or animate) the gif tiles at fixed interval. 
that looks something like this https://tangrams.github.io/carousel/?daynight#15/40.7076/-74.0094
but for non-geographical-imagery tiles.

So here is my question:

**How possible it is to render the animated gif tiles on the map?**
If it is not possible, can I use multiple layers to simulate the animation of the tiles on the map?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaflet just displays tiles as images, whether they are JPG, PNG or GIF.

There should be no issue in using animated GIF tiles, except for synchronization between each tile: as the GIF images will be displayed when loaded, and they will be loaded gradually, you have no control on the animation start time.